# Erro: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method from *"

Tags: java

Bom dia,

estou com um seguinte aviso de erro.
na linha 23 e 24 do UsuarioDAO.class.

> Diz: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method from
>   UsuarioModel.

```
    public class UsuarioDAO {

    public static Boolean doLogin(UsuarioDAO usuario) {

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String sql = "select * from usuario where nome=? and senha=?";

        try {

            // Validar
            ps = ConectarDB.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
            //UsuarioModel usuario = new UsuarioModel();
            ps.setString(1, UsuarioModel.getNome());
            ps.setString(2, usuarioModel.getSenha());
            rs=ps.executeQuery();

            // Validar
            if(rs.next()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }            

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

}

    public class UsuarioModel {

// Variáveis
    public String nome;
    public String senha;

// Getters & Setters
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public UsuarioModel(String nome, String senha) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na linha `ps.setString(1, UsuarioModel.getNome());` troque para:

`ps.setString(1, usuarioModel.getNome());`

Note que ao chamar `UsuarioModel.getNome()`, o **U** está em maiúsculo, assim o Java tentará acessar o **método estático** `getNome()` ao invés do **método de instância**, que é o que você provavelmente quer. Isso é exatamente o que a mensagem de erro está dizendo.

Answer (score 2):

Ocorre o seguinte :

```
ps.setString(1, UsuarioModel.getNome());
```

Este método não é estático:

Acredito que o que você queria fazer é salvar um `UsuarioModel` , correto?

Então você deve passar ele no parametro!

Ficaria assim:

```
 public static Boolean doLogin(UsuarioModel usuarioModel) {

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String sql = "select * from usuario where nome=? and senha=?";

        try {

            // Validar
            ps = ConectarDB.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setString(1, usuarioModel.getNome());
            ps.setString(2, usuarioModel.getSenha());
            rs=ps.executeQuery();

            // Validar
            if(rs.next()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }            

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Saudações